# Identifying the number of subjects who had treatment switch

Tags: sas

Hi SAS folks,

I am working on some research project using hospital visit data. I have to identify the subjects who had switched their treatment.

Treatments are grouped by topical, non-biologic systemic, and biologic. A switching event is defined as the withdrawal of a medication that was not dispensed at the time of the last treatment withdrawal. There is a hierarchy, with biologics at the top, then non-bio systemics, then topical.

- If a patient is first observed withdrawing a topical, any withdrawal of a treatment after that to a bio, non-bio systemic, or new topical is a switch.
- If a patient is first observed withdrawing a non-bio systemic, any withdrawal of a treatment after that to a bio or a new non-bio systemic is a switch.
- A withdrawal of any topical is not a switch.
- If a patient is first observed withdrawing a bio, a switch can only be made to another bio (which is different from the first).
- A withdrawal of any topical or non-bio systemic is not a switch.

According to the logic above, once a patient has switched to a higher class of therapy, the lower classes are considered concomitant medication and a withdrawal of a concomitant medication does not indicate a treatment switch.

In nutshell, If a patient moves from lower class of treatment to upper or withing the same class(different ATC code) then it will be consider a switch.

### Treatment hierarchy

**Biologics > Non_Bio_Sys >Topical**

I am adding sample dataset for the reference, with variable information :

```
LPNR: unique subjID
EDATUM: prescrition date ( treatment recieved date)
ATC_CODE: codes for each of treament type
          'D05AX52',
          'D05AX02' = PSorasis(Topical) ;

          'L01XC02',
          'L04AA24',
          'L04AB01',
          'L04AB02',
          'L04AB04',
          'L04AB05',
          'L04AB06',
          'L04AC03',
          'L04AC07' = Non_Bio_systemic ;

          'A11CC03',           
          'D05BB02',                
          'L01BA01',               
          'L01BB03',               
          'L01XX05',               
          'L04AA21',               
          'L04AD01',               
          'L04AX03' = Biologics ;
TYPE: Treatment type
```

### Sample data:

```
data have;
  length TYPE $20.;
  input pnr ATC_CODE $ type $ EDATUM $ 10. ;
  date=input(edatum,mmddyy10.);
  format date mmddyy10.;
  cards;
478 L04AX03 Nonbiologic_systemic 2/10/2010 
478 D05AX52 Psoriasis 2/23/2010 
478 L04AX03 Nonbiologic_systemic 3/5/2010 
478 L04AX03 Nonbiologic_systemic 5/18/2010 
478 L04AX03 Nonbiologic_systemic 8/2/2010 
478 L04AX03 Nonbiologic_systemic 11/3/2010
478 L04AX03 Nonbiologic_systemic 2/7/2011 
478 L04AX03 Nonbiologic_systemic 8/16/2011
478 L04AX03 Nonbiologic_systemic 11/22/2011
603 D05AX02 Psoriasis 8/24/2005 
603 D05AX02 Psoriasis 10/13/2005 
603 D05AX02 Psoriasis 6/2/2006
603 D05AX02 Psoriasis 7/19/2006 
603 D05AX02 Psoriasis 4/3/2007
603 D05AX02 Psoriasis 12/7/2007 
603 D05AX02 Psoriasis 1/4/2008
603 D05AX02 Psoriasis 1/4/2008 
603 D05AX02 Psoriasis 10/2/2008
603 D05AX52 Psoriasis 3/16/2009
603 D05AX52 Psoriasis 3/16/2009
603 D05AX52 Psoriasis 5/7/2009
603 D05AX52 Psoriasis 8/21/2009
603 D05AX52 Psoriasis 11/9/2009 
603 D05AX52 Psoriasis 3/19/2010 
603 D05AX52 Psoriasis 7/30/2010 
603 D05AX52 Psoriasis 7/30/2010
603 D05AX52 Psoriasis 1/13/2011 
603 D05AX52 Psoriasis 5/3/2011 
603 D05AX52 Psoriasis 12/12/2011
1103 L04AX03 Nonbiologic_systemic 1/17/2006
1103 L04AX03 Nonbiologic_systemic 8/23/2006
1103 L04AX03 Nonbiologic_systemic 11/9/2006
1103 D05AX52 Psoriasis 4/19/2007 
1103 L04AX03 Nonbiologic_systemic 4/19/2007 
1103 D05AX52 Psoriasis 10/26/2007 
1103 D05AX52 Psoriasis 4/1/2008
1103 L04AX03 Nonbiologic_systemic 10/20/2008 
1103 D05AX52 Psoriasis 10/20/2008
1103 L04AX03 Nonbiologic_systemic 4/7/2009 
1103 L04AX03 Nonbiologic_systemic 11/20/2009 
1103 L04AX03 Nonbiologic_systemic 11/12/2010 
1103 L04AX03 Nonbiologic_systemic 8/12/2011
1103 D05AX52 Psoriasis 10/22/2011 
1103 D05AX52 Psoriasis 12/29/2011
;
```

### solution I tried :

```
proc sort data=have;
  by pnr date;
run;

/* Identifying the number of subjects who had treatment switch */
data need;
  set have;
  length change $ 10.;
  by pnr;

  /* Create new variable change and keep constant if it is topical for first observation */
  /* Compare topical values with next values if it changes to other non bio or bio then switched */
  if first.pnr and atc_code in ( 'D05AX52','D05AX02') then change="";
  else if not first.pnr and atc_code not in('D05AX52','D05AX02','L01XC02','L04AA24','L04AB01',
                                            'L04AB02','L04AB04','L04AB05','L04AB06','L04AC03',
                                            'L04AC07','A11CC03','D05BB02','L01BA01','L01BB03',
                                            'L01XX05' ,'L04AA21' ,'L04AD01' ,'L04AX03') then change='switched';
  /* Compare non bio values with next values if it changes to other non bio or bio then switched*/
  if first.pnr and atc_code in ('L01XC02','L04AA24','L04AB01','L04AB02','L04AB04',
                                'L04AB05','L04AB06','L04AC03','L04AC07') then change="";
  else if not first.pnr and atc_code not in( 'D05AX52','D05AX02') and 
                            atc_code in('L01XC02','L04AA24','L04AB01','L04AB02','L04AB04','L04AB05',
                                        'L04AB06','L04AC03','L04AC07','A11CC03','D05BB02','L01BA01',
                                        'L01BB03' ,'L01XX05' ,'L04AA21' ,'L04AD01' ,'L04AX03') then change='switched';

  /* Compare bio with next values if it changes to other bio then switched */
  if first.pnr and atc_code in('A11CC03','D05BB02','L01BA01','L01BB03' ,'L01XX05' ,
                               'L04AA21' ,'L04AD01' ,'L04AX03') then change='';
  else if not first.pnr and atc_code not in('D05AX52','D05AX02') and 
                            atc_code in('A11CC03','D05BB02','L01BA01','L01BB03' ,'L01XX05',
                                        'L04AA21' ,'L04AD01' ,'L04AX03') then change='switched';

  if atc_code=lag(atc_code) then change="";                        
run;
```

### results I would expect

```
pnr   ATC_CODE  TYPE                  EDATUM      Flag_switch
478   L04AX03   Nonbiologic_systemic  2/10/2010
478   D05AX52   Psoriasis             2/23/2010
478   L04AX03   Nonbiologic_systemic  5/18/2010   switch
478   L04AX03   Nonbiologic_systemic  8/2/2010
478   L04AX03   Nonbiologic_systemic  11/3/2010
478   L04AX03   Nonbiologic_systemic  2/7/2011
478   L04AX03   Nonbiologic_systemic  8/16/2011
478   L04AX03   Nonbiologic_systemic  11/22/2011
603   D05AX02   Psoriasis             8/24/2005
603   D05AX02   Psoriasis             10/13/2005
603   D05AX02   Psoriasis             6/2/2006
603   D05AX02   Psoriasis             7/19/2006
603   D05AX02   Psoriasis             4/3/2007
603   D05AX02   Psoriasis             12/7/2007
603   D05AX02   Psoriasis             1/4/2008
603   D05AX02   Psoriasis             10/2/2008
603   D05AX52   Psoriasis             3/16/2009   switch
603   D05AX52   Psoriasis             5/7/2009
603   D05AX52   Psoriasis             8/21/2009
603   D05AX52   Psoriasis             11/9/2009
603   D05AX52   Psoriasis             3/19/2010
603   D05AX52   Psoriasis             7/30/2010
603   D05AX52   Psoriasis             1/13/2011
603   D05AX52   Psoriasis             5/3/2011
603   D05AX52   Psoriasis             12/12/2011
1103  L04AX03   Nonbiologic_systemic  1/17/2006
1103  L04AX03   Nonbiologic_systemic  8/23/2006
1103  L04AX03   Nonbiologic_systemic  11/9/2006
1103  L04AX03   Nonbiologic_systemic  4/19/2007
1103  D05AX52   Psoriasis             10/26/2007
1103  D05AX52   Psoriasis             4/1/2008
1103  L04AX03   Nonbiologic_systemic  10/20/2008  switch
1103  D05AX52   Psoriasis             10/20/2008
1103  L04AX03   Nonbiologic_systemic  4/7/2009    switch
1103  L04AX03   Nonbiologic_systemic  11/20/2009
1103  L04AX03   Nonbiologic_systemic  11/12/2010
1103  L04AX03   Nonbiologic_systemic  8/12/2011
1103  D05AX52   Psoriasis             10/22/2011
1103  D05AX52   Psoriasis             12/29/2011
```

Comment: Please reformat your question so its not all using a code block.

Comment: @Reeza. I reformatted the question. Thank you for your help.

Comment: Question was still unreadable... please verify that my formatting is adequate.

Comment: @ Dominic Hi , Thanks for the quick reply. I am sorry for the unclear explaination, but what i exactly means is:
as you see the data, we have three treatment type in TYPE variable. Now for each Type variable we have different ATC_CODEs. I need to identify the event (SWITCH) , whenever subject changes his treatment type from Lower treatment type( i,e Topical) to Higher treatment group(i,e Non_bio_sys or Biologics) during his treatment period. Same is true for Non_sys_Bio , if Subject changes to Biologics, then it will also consider as Switch.

Comment: continuous-Event is also to be counted whenever subjects changes his ATC_CODEs within his treatment TYPE , ie in case, when Treatment TYPE is "Psorasis" and if Its' ATC_CODE changes , then we have to identify it as SWITCH.
 same is true for other treatment arm.
 
order of treatment: BIOLOGICS> NON_BIO_SYS> TOPICAL.
 
Hope i am able to clear you doubt. please help. thanks

Comment: @DominicComtois please check last two comments. I explained clearly

Comment: There are two ways by which you can compare rows with one another: the lag() function, which has its quirks, and the more reliable IMO retain statement, often used in conjuncture with the by statement of the data step. You could also put several variables on the `by` statement (which is, I think, what you were getting at). Coding values with numbers and using custom formats (with `proc format`) might also make it all easier -- you'd then compare numbers (which would reflect the hierarchy) rather than strings.

Comment: @DominicComtois thank you for reply .  can you please show me in code?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Okay. So here is one out of several possible solutions. You will still need to work out the switches for treatment type 3 (Biologics), and figure out how to handle places where you have several entries on the same date. But this should get you going!

### Preparing the data

```
proc format;
  value treatType 1 = "Topical"
                  2 = "Non-biologic systemics"
                  3 = "Biologics";
run;

data have;
  format pnr 8. tType treatType. tCode $10. date YYMMDDs8.;
  informat tType 1. date yymmdd10.;
  input pnr tCode tType date;
  datalines;
478 L04AX03 2 2010-02-10
478 D05AX52 1 2010-02-23
478 L04AX03 2 2010-03-05
478 L04AX03 2 2010-05-18
478 L04AX03 2 2010-08-02
478 L04AX03 2 2010-11-03
478 L04AX03 2 2011-02-07
478 L04AX03 2 2011-08-16
478 L04AX03 2 2011-11-22
603 D05AX02 1 2005-08-24
603 D05AX02 1 2005-10-13
603 D05AX02 1 2006-06-02
603 D05AX02 1 2006-07-19
603 D05AX02 1 2007-04-03
603 D05AX02 1 2007-12-07
603 D05AX02 1 2008-01-04
603 D05AX02 1 2008-01-04
603 D05AX02 1 2008-10-02
603 D05AX52 1 2009-03-16
603 D05AX52 1 2009-03-16
603 D05AX52 1 2009-05-07
603 D05AX52 1 2009-08-21
603 D05AX52 1 2009-11-09
603 D05AX52 1 2010-03-19
603 D05AX52 1 2010-07-30
603 D05AX52 1 2010-07-30
603 D05AX52 1 2011-01-13
603 D05AX52 1 2011-05-03
603 D05AX52 1 2011-12-12
1103 L04AX03 2 2006-01-17
1103 L04AX03 2 2006-08-23
1103 L04AX03 2 2006-11-09
1103 D05AX52 1 2007-04-19
1103 L04AX03 2 2007-04-19
1103 D05AX52 1 2007-10-26
1103 D05AX52 1 2008-04-01
1103 L04AX03 2 2008-10-20
1103 D05AX52 1 2008-10-20
1103 L04AX03 2 2009-04-07
1103 L04AX03 2 2009-11-20
1103 L04AX03 2 2010-11-12
1103 L04AX03 2 2011-08-12
1103 D05AX52 1 2011-10-22
1103 D05AX52 1 2011-12-29
run;
```

### Calculating the switch variable

```
proc sort data=have;
  by pnr date;
run;

data want;
  set have;
  by pnr;
  format switch 1. tCode_prev $10. tType_prev 3.;
  retain tCode_prev '' tType_prev .;
  format switch 1.;

  if first.pnr then do;
    switch = 0;
  end;

  else if tType_prev = 1 then do;
    if tType > 1 or tCode ne tCode_prev then switch = 1;
    else switch = 0;
  end;

  else if tType_prev = 2 then do;
    if tType > 2 or (tType = 2 and tCode ne tCode_prev) then switch = 1;
    else switch = 0;
  end;

  else if tType_prev = 3 then do;
    /* Here's your homework */
  end;

  output;    
  tCode_prev = tCode;
  tType_prev = tType;

  drop tCode_prev tType_prev;
run;
```